# Display TextBox Or TextBlock depending on value of a Flag

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

In my WPF application, my Viewmodel has a boolean property `IsOwnerOf` and a string property `Title`. If `IsOwner==false`, I want a `TextBlock` displaying the `Title` (because if you're not the owner, you should not be able to edit it) and if `IsOwner==true`, I want a `TextBox` displaying `Title` - obviously at the same place in the view.

Also I don't want to do it codebehind since I follow the MVVM pattern. Thought about `Style.Triggers`, but with them I can only influence attributes of an element, not the element type itself, or can I?

EDIT:
Practically the answers below regarding triggering `Visibility` or `IsReadOnly` work, but I still would like to see a conceptually better answer! What if I replace the `TextBox` resp. `TextBlock` by elements that don't have these convenient properties? There must be a better way than creating both and hiding one of them, that just doesn't sound right...

Comment: Have you just considered a TextBox and bind the ReadOnly property to !IsOwnerOf  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You can bind the visibility of your controls to the boolean property. Here's an article to help you http://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/

Comment: Please post your markup *and* the view model. Also, please read this article to help you understand why there are certain pieces to a question that need to exist (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, sure, I understand, but all is standard here, so I though I omit the code... Also, to the fisrt two comments, see my comments to the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to always drop a `TextBox` and bind it's `IsEnabled` or `IsReadOnly` property to the `IsOwner` flag.

You can also use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to achieve this.

Comment: Sure, but a TextBox looks different, it "suggests editability" to the user, whereas a TextBlock not.

Comment: Thanks! The `DatatemplateSelector` is the solution I was looking for, i.e., I make two templates, one containing the `TextBlock`, the other one the `TextBox`, and then I choose the template according to the value of the flag.

Comment: @ToaoG You're welcome. I wanted to improve the answer and give a sample code for the template selector approach, but I didn't found the time. I'm gald you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use triggers to change the `Visibility` of your `TextBlock` and `TextBox` using a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`

Comment: So you suggest to always have both present, and just juggle the visibility depending on the value of IsOwnerOf? That seems like a waste of resources to me, because I create more objects than I need, and hence not the best practice. Or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @ToaoG, I would say that's irrelevant. You're talking about two objects - and keep in mind that a `TextBlock` doesn't even have a window handle.

Comment: Ok, granted it is of minimal concern here, but the question was also of broader interest, i.e., what should I do in a similar situation, where I want to toggle between different elements depending on the value of a flag, which dont necessarily have a `readonly` or `visibility` property? What is the cleanest way? This one seems like ad hoc problem solving, sry.

Comment: @ToaoG Ad hoc? Visibility is a property of UIElement.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx